# defining highcharts in body

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to use highcharts in my system but the limitation of having to define the entire content and style of the highchart object in the < head > is destroying my architecture.
Is there a way I could describe the highchart object < script > section within the body?

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/

I did a bunch of experiments and with a flat html file I managed to just put the < script > inside < body > and defined the < div id="container" >< /div > right below it and that worked.
For some unknown reason though when I try the same trick in my php system (which cuts and pastes various section of the html together to produce the final page, it does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can place the content and style definition in an external file, and simply reference it in the document head:

```
<script src="url_to_your_file.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi George thanks for the suggestion but my challenge is that the data that I'm feeding is retrieved from the database at runtime, basically I have PHP code in my javascript and the system is designed that all should be one in one block. Is there any way to modify highcharts to have this behavior, maybe instead of specifying a container to render to can't I just make it output where it's called from?